# Are there systems in classical mechanics that are provably non-deterministic?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, determinism, randomness

N body problems mostly don't admit any algebraic solutions although they can be solved numerically at least in principle. Determinism basically is the claim that given any system and its initial conditions one could in theory always calculate all the information about that system in any given time. This leads to the concept of deterministic chaos, systems that are very sensitive to initial conditions tend to be for all practical purposes unpredictable and therfore their state undeterminable. But theoretically given any amount of computing power can you determine the state of any classical system, or is classical physics not a completely deterministic theory?

This is not about non uniqueness or some artificial examples. The point is for example the problem of the stability of the solar system. Given a gravitating n body system can you find its state at any time t. Can this be proven to be undecidable.

Comment: Related/possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81375/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141111/50583

Comment: Yes. Norton’s dome for example.

Comment: Thats not what I'm asking (Norton dome).

Comment: It's not at all about non uniqueness of solutiins, quite the opposite actually

Comment: unclear why Norton's dome does not qualify?

Comment: There are systems that produce an output that can't be determined by classical mechanics, for example if you use the output of a Geiger counter to decide when to kick a ball down a hill.

Comment: Not the question..

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [What situations in classical physics are non-deterministic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/403574)

Comment: The title of the question and the last paragraph are in conflict. Norton's dome is provably non-deterministic, end of story. So which is it you are asking about, the provability of non-deterministic systems in classical mechanics (in which case this question is a duplicate), or the stability of the solar system?

Comment: If the question is about the stability of the solar system, the following are highly related, if not duplicates: [Question on the stability of the solar system](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8827),  [Are orbits interior to Jupiter's orbit less stable than orbits exterior to Jupiter's orbit?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26007), [Lyapunov stability of circular orbits](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240915), and [Is the orbit of the planets around the Sun chaotic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11661)

Comment: I'll think about it.

Comment: @David hammen. As I said Norton dome is a nice but purely non physical artificial example. It has no physical realization. Whereas the n body problem has. None of the similar questions had proper and definitive answers on the question I'm asking.

Comment: The question is both about purely formal undecidability and its physical realization.